# JPA: uni-directional OneToMany question

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following classes:

```
class A{
   @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private B b;
}

class C{
  @ManyToOne
  private A a;    
}

class B{
  @OneToOne
  private A a;

  @MapKey(name = "name")
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, ...)
  @JoinColumn(...)
  private Map<String C> cs;
}
```

How do I have to specify the mapping on B.cs to join where B.a == C.a?

Is this possible? Or do I have to change the property C.a to C.b? (I would prefer to keep it as it is, as the entity B is just a helper class.)
I also tried to change B to @Embeddable, but Map is not supported for embeddables.

Answer (score 1):

JPA requires that all relationships be by Id (the foreign key references the primary key).
So, you need to either add a @ManyToOne from C to B.
Or, ensure that B's Id is the foreign key to A (add @Id on the @OneToOne from B to A and remove A's other @Id).
If B was a subclass of A instead of having a OneToOne this would also work.

If you are using EclipseLink, you can defined more complex criteria for a relationship.  You would need to define the OneToMany's foreign keys using a DescriptorCustomizer and the OneToManyMapping API.

Comment: The foreign key (in C) references a primary key (A), it's just not the primary key of B. I think I struggle with the fact that JPA doesn't allow me to define B as @Embeddable. But you say I only have these 3 choices: @ManyToOne from C to B, @ID on @OneToOne from B to A (is this a good practice?) or  EclipseLink specific mapping (leaving the JPA standard), right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can extends B from A.

<strike>If this doesn't work for you, maybe you can add a transient property to refer A's id,</strike>

```
@Transient
Integer getId1() {
    return a.getId();
}
```

and join C using `id1` instead of B's primary key.

*Edit: This doesn't work.*

Comment: What do you mean with "derive"? Inheritance?. This is a composition where A has some more properties and B has some more properties. An is-a relation ship (inheritance) would be wrong here.

Comment: I mean 'extends' here. Maybe you are right. In this case, personally I will make another base class _A, and make A and B extends _A.